# Features turned off in Windows 10 Pro, after reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microsoft-surface

The system in question is a Microsoft Surface Book 2, running Windows 10 Pro.

I would like to turn on the following Windows features:

- Hyper-V
- Containers
- Windows Subsystem for Linux

I'm able to turn these features on, either via the shell (as admin), or via the "Turn Windows features on or off" interface. However, when I reboot the system, these features become turned off again.

Furthermore, if I open msconfig, and switch from "Selective Startup" to "Normal Startup", the system will revert back to "Selective Startup" on reboot.

I tried running "sfc /scannow", and it fixed filesystem errors. However, it did not resolve the aforementioned issues.

Comment: Try to use the `dism` commands.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I ran dism and then ran sfc /scannow again. Afterwards, I performed a system update. The problem is resolved. Thank you!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness